# Issue: Webpack in VS2015 not refreshing the Browser on any change in TypeScript File

Tags: typescript, webpack, visual-studio-2015, angular5, webpack-dev-server

In VS2015, I have MVC Project in which I have Angular 5 app. On changing any typescript file, the TaskRunner detects the change, but the browser does not reload.

Code For Webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var WebpackNotifierPlugin = require('webpack-notifier');

module.exports = {
    context: path.join(__dirname, 'App'),
    entry: './main.js',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'Built'),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js'
    },
    plugins: [
      new WebpackNotifierPlugin()
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css" },
            { test: /\.jpe?g$|\.gif$|\.png$|\.svg$|\.woff$|\.ttf$|\.eot$/, loader: "url" },
            { test: /\.html$/, loader: "html" }
        ]
    }
};
```

Code For package.json

```
{
  "name": "webpack-demo",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.4",
    "style-loader": "^0.12.2",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.6",
    "webpack-notifier": "^1.2.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~1.7.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0"
  }
}
```

Image that Task Runner Refreshes on Code Change

[image]

Image that Task Runner --> Run Development, Watch Development, Serve Hot:

[image]

Comment: That's because you have do not have hot module replacement enabled. If your webpack is not run with the `--hot` option, then you have to specify it via the `devServer.hot` option: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/816

Comment: @Terry: I am running the following options from Task Runner Explorer: Run Development, Watch Development, Server Hot. I have attached the screenshot in the question. But still the browser is not refreshed. I am runnign the application using F5 in VS 2015